# Back button changing iframe content page in web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Happy holidays all!

I have a web app page that contains templates that user can select from. There is an iframe to preview the template in a4/print mode at the bottom of the page.

The user can select the various templates using some thumbnail / buttons on the page.

I notice today that the browser's back button just changes the page inside the iFrame and not the page in the main browser. This only happens in Chrome (latest ver) and MS Edge (latest ver). It works as desired in FF (also latest). I have yet to confirm Safari.

The back button keeps reloading the iframe with any pages in history, and it never exits the main page. So it loads other pages that were never meant/loaded in the iFrame, for as long as there is a history.

Based on research, I changed the JS that loads the iFrame from this:

```
$('iframe#template-iframe').attr('src', templateRoute);
```

to this

```
var iframeElement = $('iframe#template-iframe').get(0);
iframeElement.contentWindow.location.replace(templateRoute);
```

I am managing the back button via back end PHP and JS to avoid going back to certain pages (like a POST on checkout).

```
currentURL = location.pathname;
history.replaceState(null, '', previousURL);
history.pushState(null,    '', currentURL);

window.addEventListener("popstate", function() {
    history.replaceState(null, '', currentURL);
    setTimeout(function() {
        setCookie("back_button_cookie",99);
        location.replace(previousURL);
    }, 0);
}, false);
```

The issue remains after the changes. I want the iFrame to be ignored by the back button. Is there something I missed in my "back button JS code" above?

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can try bellow code

```
var iframeElement = $('iframe#template-iframe').get(0);
changeIframeSrc(iframeElement,templateRoute);

var changeIframeSrc = function(iframe, src) {
    var frame = iframe.cloneNode();
    frame.src = src;
    iframe.parentNode.replaceChild(frame, iframe);
};
```

Comment: Hi @Bharatsing Parmar thanks for the response. Your code works fine on page load, and on change of iframe content the first time, it fails on the second change with `cannot read property of replaceChild`. Also, the back button behaviour remains, with the iframe page being changed.